# Special case: wrong order of updates for fly-away

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tclientdataset

How can I track down the location of the "*Special case: wrong order of updates for fly-away!*" error?

This error message is defined in `Datasnap.DSIntf` as

```
const
  ...
  ERRCODE_FLYAWAY_WRONGORDER = 13;  { Special case: wrong order of updates for fly-away }
  ...
  DBERR_FLYAWAY_WRONGORDER  = ERRBASE_ALC + ERRCODE_FLYAWAY_WRONGORDER;
```

but nowhere else in the Delphi sources can I find references to substring FLYAWAY_WRONGORDER.<sup>*</sup>

My intention was to compile with debug dcu's, then put a breakpoint on the line where the exception is raised and check the call stack UP to find the cause.
I'm currently stepping DOWN into the code until the error occurs, but that is less efficient (complex app).

Placing a `TApplicationEvents` with a breakpoint in its OnException handler does not give me usable call stack information:

[image]

So, how can I (efficiently) track down the place where this error is generated?

Background on what is going on:

- Form uses DevExpress `TcxScheduler` connected to `TcxSchedulerStorage` component in datamodule, connected to nested `TClientDataSet`s
- Code saves all changes to these datasets (ApplyUpdates)
- In BeginUpdate/EndUpdate for these DevExpress components, I then insert, delete and update records in these datasets, move around while doing so, even change parent IDs in detail datasets so that they drop from the current detail dataset 'in view'.
  The error occurs when I Edit, then Post a record doing exactly that.
- Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3, Win32 app
- Any other info on that error message is welcome, I was not able to find anything.

I actually 'fixed' the error by calling ApplyUpdates for the master dataset in a few places, but since I'm not really sure about the cause I want to investigate this further. So my question is not *How do I fix the error in my code*, it is *How do I* **find** *the error in my code*?

<sup>* There is a CheckForFlyAway routine in `TCustomADODataSet.InternalPost` in `Data.Win.ADODB` but we don't use ADO, I cannot set breakpoints in those routines.</sup>

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `Exception.StackTrace` property in the `OnException` event? It does require installing a 3rd party exception logger first, though, such as MadExcept, EurekaLog, JclDebug, etc, something to actually generate the stack trace data since the RTL will not generate it automatically.

Comment: Often it is due to a record you created/modified vanishing due to a WHERE that excludes it.